# Add Modal Component To Card component in React

Tags: reactjs

I have created two different components, one for a card and one for a modal. What I would like to do now is to connect them together so that when I click the button on the card component, I would like the modal to open up on the screen. I have tried all that I can but can't seem to get it right.

Here is the card compenent:

```
import img from './112803.jpg';
import GitHub from './github-white.png';
import Website from './website-white.png';
import ModalButton from './ModalButton.js'

function Card(props) {
    return (
      <div className="card">
  <div className="cardBody">

    <div className="imageOverlay">
    <img className="imageOverlayImg" src={img} alt="landscape" />
      <div className="imageOverlayDescription">

        <a href={props.gitHub} target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">
        <img src={GitHub} alt="GitHub Icon" /> 
        </a>

        <a href={props.liveSite} target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">
        <img src={Website} alt="liveSite Icon" /> 
        </a> 
       
      </div>
    </div>

      <h2 className="cardTitle">{props.heading}</h2>
      <p className="cardDescription">{props.description}</p>
  </div>
  <button className="cardButton">More Information</button>

  

</div>
    );
  }
  
  export default Card;
```

And here is the modal component:

```
        const Modal =(props)=>{
    
    return(
    
      <> 
       {props.showModal ? (
        <div className="background">
        <div className='modalWrapper' showModal={props.showModal}>

            <img clasName="modalImg" src={require('./deals.jpg').default} alt="A Landscape" width="100%" height="100%"/>
          
            <div className="modalContent">
                <h1>{props.heading}</h1>
               <p>{props.description}</p>
               <p>{props.madeBy}</p>
                <div className="buttonLayout">
                <button className="innerModalButton"><a href={props.viewCode} target="_blank" rel="noreferrer">View Code</a></button>
                <button className="innerModalButton"><a href={props.viewSite} target="_blank" rel="noreferrer">Live Site</a></button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <button className="closeModalButton" aria-label="Close modal" onClick={()=> 

    props.setShowModal(prev => !prev)}>Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    ) : null} 
    
    </>
    
    );
    }
```

And here is some of the logic that the modal needs in order to pop up

```
         const [showModal,setShowModal] = useState(false);
    
    const openModal = () =>{
    
      setShowModal(prev => !prev)
```

I am still a bit of a beginner and I'm not too sure how to get the project done. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a state in Card pass pass it into `Modal`:

```
const [showModal,setShowModal] = useState(false);

...
<Modal
  showModal={showModal}
  setShowModal={setShowModal}
  //...another props to display content
/>
```

Comment: Hello there.So what i did was add the state to my modal component. Then I added the modal to the inside of the card but it still does not seem to work.

Comment: add state in the `Card` component and pass it to `Modal` component

Comment: I have done that too but it still does not work. Is there a specific place where I should pass the state into the Modal? Right now I have the state in the card and have passed it down to modal and use that State in Modal but it doesn't work, or maybe the modal button is not working correctly?

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding of what is going on, it looks like your modal button isn't doing anything. I would suggest you add an onClick method to it.

```
<button className="cardButton" onClick={()=> setShowModal(true)}> More Information</button>
```

Also like the answer above, pass the state from the card to the Modal
That could do it.

Let me know if it helped.